# "hostname" Publishing Azure Bot from Composer

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service, bot-framework-composer

I am currently attempting to deploy a bot from Composer to an Azure Bot Services resource I have already provisioned (bot handle sherlockchatbot, app registration SherlockHSEChatbotProd). After selecting "Import existing resources", I have attempted to fill in the Publish Configuration, however it is unclear what to put in the "hostname" field. I have attempted every combination of the name, app registration name, and bot handle with the environment name, but repeatedly get the same error when attempting to publish the bot. I examined the docs and was unable to find an answer. Below is a segment of my Publish Configuration (omitting confidential/unnecessary information):

```
{ "name": "SherlockV1.0",
  "environment": "dev",
  "hostname": "sherlockchatbot-dev",
  "resourceGroup": "AZ-RG-HSChatbot-Dev-01",
  "botName": "sherlockchatbot",
```

How can I identify what I put for "hostname" and is there an easier way to deploy a bot to my created Azure Bot resource? I cannot provision new resources through composer as I work at a large company and my permissions are restricted.

Here is the error message when attempting to publish:

> DEPLOY_ZIP_ERROR - There was a problem publishing bot assets (zip deploy). {"stack":"Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND sherlockchatbot-dev.\n at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup.....

Answer (score 0):

the hostname refers to the web App that hosts your bot. So the hostname should be the Azure WebApp Name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide value in

"hostname": "Your Botname",
**"scmHostDomain" : "scm.azurewebsites.net"**